# QR decomposition of matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I have matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ is $N\times N$, $B$ is $N\times 2$ and I have $Q$, $R$ such that $A = QR$. What is the fastest way to find $Q'$ and $R'$ that satisfy $M = Q'R'$?

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}Q & 0\\0 & I_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}R & Q^TB\\B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can compute a QR-decomposition of $\begin{pmatrix}R & Q^TB\\B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}$ with 2N Givens-rotations. With the result we can build a QR-decomposition of the original matrix. However I am not sure if this is the fastest way to do it.